# Use One Javascript Function For Multiple GridViews

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a JS function to toggle check state for all the checkboxes in a gridview. Now, there are two similar gridviews and so, would like to use the same function.

> This is Page structure:
>
> Radiobutton rb1, RadioButton rb2
>
> Gridview gv1, gridview gv2.
>
> rb1 selected, shows only gv1 and hides gv2 and vice versa.
>
> On page load, only rb1 is checked and gv1 is visble.

The JS function works fine when used for just one gridview. I changed it to this and it doesnt work. Where am I going wrong.

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function SelectAll(chkBox)
{
  var chkAll = document.getElementById(chkBox);
  var elements;
  var g1 = document.getElementById('<%=gv1.ClientID%>');
  var g2 = document.getElementById('<%=gv2.ClientID%>');
  if(g1.style.visibility=='visible')
   {
    elements = document.getElementById('<%=gv1.ClientID%>')
            .getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
   }
  else if(g2.style.visibility=='visible')
   {
     elements = document.getElementById('<%=gv2.ClientID%>')
            .getElementsByTageName("INPUT");
   }
 for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
  {    
   var chk;
   if(elements[i]!=null)
    {
      if(elements[i].id.indexof('chkLeaveType')>0)
          {
               chk=elements[i];
               chk.checked = chkAll.checked;    
          }            
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**ASPX:**
    
     
      
      
     
     
    
    
       
       
        
         onclick="SelectAll(this.id)"/>Leave Type

```
<asp:gridview id="gv2" runat="server">
<columns>
  <asp:templatefield> 
   <headertemplate>   
    <asp:checkbox id="chkheader" runat="server" checked="true" 
     onclick="SelectAll(this.id)"/>Leave Type  
   </headertemplate>
   <itemtemplate>
      <asp:checkbox id="chkLeaveType" runat="server" checked="true"/>
   </itemtemplate>
  </asp:templatefield> 
</columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems I see:

1. You are attempting (I believe) to get all child checkboxes with this bit of code:

   ```
   elements = document.getElementById('the grid id')
       .document.getElementById("INPUT");
   ```

   But, unless I much mistake,  `getElementById` does what it says:  gets you the element BY *ID*, not by tag name.  You'd need `getElementsByTagName` to get the elements by their tag.
2. Also, by using this code (non-compilable dashes added for emphasis)

   ```
      document.getElementById('the grid id').document.getElementById("INPUT")   
      --------                               --------
   ```

   ... you are jumping back to the top of the DOM, the `document`, and will be pulling children from the entire document, not from just the grid you want. You might want to try something like this, leaving out the jump back to the `document` node:

   ```
   document.getElementById('the grid id').getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
   ```
3. Finally, you might want to look at `jquery` (just a suggestion) as it makes doing this sort of thing much more simple.

Comment: Sorry. That was a Typo from my end. It was actually...getElementByTagName("INPUT"); Could you plz suggest abt the procedure. What else do i need to do to make it work.

Comment: I think you are also missing a final `}`.  The count looks off to me.

Comment: If that doesn't help, I'd check that `g1.style.visibility=='visible'` really is true when grid 1 is displayed, using your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: The count was again a typo. I have edited to make it more readable now.

Comment: I dont see gv2 in pageSource at all!!!.How come. When I change checkbox selections it works, but in page source, no gv2 !!!. Is it beacuse, its inside an update panel.

Comment: The page source will show you the page as it was sent down to the browser.  It won't reflect changes that were made after that happened.  So if `gv2` is inside an update panel, and doesn't appear until the update panel is updated, it won't show in the page source.